# Changing the mark of endnotes

Tags: numbering, footnotes, endnotes

I am using **both** footnotes and endnotes in a chapter with the help of the `endnotes` package.

However, both footnotes and endnotes are numbered by Arabic number.

I would like to keep the Arabic numbers for the footnotes, but I would like to change the mark of the endnotes to Roman numbers, or some other symbols.

Comment: That works perfectly ! Thank you !

Is there a similar way to convert the endnote marks in dagger, starts, etc. ?

Comment: `\renewcommand\theendnote{\fnsymbol{endnote}}` should do. Beware that only a limited set of symbols is provided and too large counter numbers can cause errors.

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\Roman{endnote}}
```

to your document preamble. Also, taking from cgnieder's comment,

```
\renewcommand\theendnote{\fnsymbol{endnote}}
```

should give you a symbol set for the endnotes rather than Roman numerals. There is a limited set though, as can be seen from a subsidiary definition of `\@fnsymbol` in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
```

So, you'll receive the following output:

1. `*` -> *
2. `\dagger` -> †
3. `\ddagger` -> ‡
4. `\mathsection` -> §
5. `\mathparagraph` -> ¶
6. `\|` -> ||
7. `**` -> **
8. `\dagger\dagger` -> ††
9. `\ddagger\ddagger` -> ‡‡
10. Error