# Change the style of the endnote to numbers with a circle

Tags: circles, endnotes

I've read [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88536/changing-the-mark-of-endnotes) and I want to add circles to these arabic numbers for endnotes.
By the way, I would like to keep the Arabic numbers for the footnotes.

```
\renewcommand\theendnote{\textcircled{\@arabic\c@endnote}}
```

Code above went wrong.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't use @ like this because it's a special character. You need to include your command between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to make it work.

Comment: @SebGlav I've done so and it still went wrong. The problem occured in the ".ent" file, saying"Missing $ inserted.<inserted text> ".

Comment: It's impossible to know what's going wrong with your example without a minimal working example, but the command you give should be `\renewcommand\theendnote{\textcircled{\arabic{endnote}}}`. The names with `@` are internal names that you should generally avoid unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem.
It isn't so simple as I thought before, though.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xunicode-addon}
%
% common settings
%

% use specific font inside \textcircled
% ref: https://stone-zeng.github.io/2019-02-09-circled-numbers
\AtBeginUTFCommand[\textcircled]{\begingroup\EnclosedNumbers}
\AtEndUTFCommand[\textcircled]{\endgroup}

% set char class and font for circled numbers
\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{Default}{"24EA, "2460->"2473, "3251->"32BF}
\newfontfamily\EnclosedNumbers{Source Han Serif SC}

% for use on overleaf, you can try
% \AtBeginUTFCommand[\textcircled]{\begingroup\normalsize\EnclosedNumbers}
% \newfontfamily\EnclosedNumbers{Garamond-Math.otf}
\renewcommand\theendnote{\textcircled@protected{\@arabic\c@endnote}}

% a protected variant for use in \theendnote, which will be fully-expanded
\protected\def\textcircled@protected{\textcircled}

% overleaf doesn't like this approach
% \let\textcircled@old\textcircled
% \protected\def\textcircled#1{%
%  \expandafter\textcircled@old\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}}

% adjust position of circled number
\xpatchcmd\enoteformat
  {\makeenmark}
  {\makeenmark@nosuperscript}
  {}{\fail}
% before
% \def\@makeenmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@theenmark}}}
\def\makeenmark@nosuperscript{%
  \lower .3ex \hbox{\normalfont\@theenmark\space}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Footnotes}
xxx\footnote{text}

\addtocounter{footnote}{20}
xxx\footnote{text}

\addtocounter{footnote}{20}
xxx\footnote{text}

\section{Endnotes}
xxx\endnote{text}
    
\addtocounter{endnote}{20}
xxx\endnote{text}

\addtocounter{endnote}{20}
xxx\endnote{text}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/muzimuzhi/latex-examples/blob/master/examples/footnote-chinese-style.tex).